# Front End Testing Strategies?

Tags: javascript, performance, frontend, user-experience, performance-testing

I am a front ed developer and was thinking whether there is a full blown testing strategies for front end. Since there are a lot of front end tools and we are using one each day. Are there any specific set of methodologies that are being followed in order to develop rich UI with great performance? I think of few things that should be taken care of like

1. Using Sprites
2. Checking my JavaScript Consistanncy
3. Checking page load time

What are the other aspects that one feels to concentrate on so as to build the most robust front end possible. How ca we test them and what are the different Strategies that are being employed. Please help me out to figure these out.

Comment: Whoever pointe my question as not a real question, I would request the m to atleast point me to some source of information to show I am asking something lame.

Comment: I don't know why they closed your question but maybe try and rephrase, I would be interested to see an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried qunit?

[Link](http://qunitjs.com/)

I like it because its easy to write your own tests...
For pageload time you can use PageSpeed plugin for google chrome, its giving you nice feedback about what to improve